# Classes cannot directly extend java.lang.Enum

Tags: java

I am getting the error classes cannot directly extends `java.lang.enum` in my following code

```
public final class ConversionMode extends Enum
{

public static final ConversionMode TO_XLIFF;
public static final ConversionMode FROM_XLIFF;
private static final ConversionMode $VALUES[];

public static final ConversionMode[] values()
{
    return (ConversionMode[])$VALUES.clone();
}

public static ConversionMode valueOf(String s)
{
    return (ConversionMode)Enum.valueOf(file2xliff4j/ConversionMode, s);
}

private ConversionMode(String s, int i)
{
    super(s, i);
}

static 
{
    TO_XLIFF = new ConversionMode("TO_XLIFF", 0);
    FROM_XLIFF = new ConversionMode("FROM_XLIFF", 1);
    $VALUES = (new ConversionMode[] {
        TO_XLIFF, FROM_XLIFF
    });
}
}
```

I also refer this link, but I am getting it properly so please give me the solution what I need to do?

Comment: why are you extending a class with enum? What is your purpose?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar: Possibly trying to recompile disassembled code?

Comment: This will help you . http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/01/why-use-enumerations-in-java/

Comment: @Prasad Kharkar if(mode.equals(ConversionMode.TO_XLIFF) && filetype == null)
        {
            return "Specify the file type.";
        }

In this function i want to access ConversionMode value what should i need to do?

Answer (score 8):

That's not how you create an enum in Java. Here's how you do it:

```
public enum ConversionMode {
    TO_XLIFF,
    FROM_XLIFF
}
```

That's all. The `values()`, `valueOf()`, `ordinal()` and other enum methods are implemented for you.

As always in Java, there is a [tutorial about enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot extends `ENUM`

[JLS#8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

> An enum type is implicitly final unless it contains at least one enum constant that has a class body.

Example

```
enum Color {
    RED, GREEN, BLUE;

}
```

If you see the [Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), a complete example is there how to use Enum and getting values etc ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not how to make enums.  You don't extend enum.

```
public enum ConversionMode {
    TO_XLIFF,
    FROM_XLIFF,
...
```