# Java Enum is abstract class, how it create own instance

Tags: java, enums

As I know, Enum is abstract class, I write an Enum, then I do javap command, I got:

```
public abstract class com.tonyzhai.homework.TestEnum extends java.lang.Enum<com.tonyzhai.homework.TestEnum> {
  public static final com.tonyzhai.homework.TestEnum a;

  public static com.tonyzhai.homework.TestEnum[] values();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field $VALUES:[Lcom/tonyzhai/homework/TestEnum;
       3: invokevirtual #3                  // Method "[Lcom/tonyzhai/homework/TestEnum;".clone:()Ljava/lang/Object;
       6: checkcast     #4                  // class "[Lcom/tonyzhai/homework/TestEnum;"
       9: areturn

  public static com.tonyzhai.homework.TestEnum valueOf(java.lang.String);
```

so, it cannot instantiation, my question is that abstract must be has no instance, so if use Enum implement Singleton pattern, how it create its own instance?

Comment: It would help if you'd show the Java source code... A simple enum doesn't end up generating an abstract class, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Why are you looking at the java disassembler output? What is the source code?

Comment: Enum instances in Java are always instantiated when you declare them (that's when the constructor is called).

Comment: Reflection says enum classes are not abstract ([demo](http://ideone.com/Wtdi23)).

Comment: [`java.lang.Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) is indeed abstract, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: If you are trying to implement a singleton, why not use `enum` instead of extending `Enum`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I believe the implementation of `enum` classes is abstract if and only if the individual enum constants override behavior from the top-level enum type.

Comment: when i define a variable, the class became final class, not abstract, but it still cannot reflect, when i get Class.newInstance(), i got NoSuchMethodException, i debug the code, found enum has a default Enum(int , string), so I define a empty constructor in my Enum class, but still got this exception, why? what the root reason it is not reflect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare an `enum`, the compiler will fill in certain aspects to fulfill the contract. E.g. it will add a `YourEnumType[] values()` and a `YourEnumType valueOf(String)` method.

It will also make your constructor `private`, regardless of whether you declared it, and it will add implicit `int` and `String` parameters whose arguments get passed to the super constructor [`Enum(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#Enum-java.lang.String-int-). These match the name and ordinal and the compiler will also insert the appropriate arguments when the constants are created.

For example:

```
public enum Axis {
    HORIZONTAL(true), VERTICAL(false);

    private boolean isHorizontal;

    Axis(boolean horizontal) {
        isHorizontal=horizontal;
    }
    public Axis getOther() {
        return isHorizontal? VERTICAL: HORIZONTAL;
    }
    public static void main(String... arg) {
        for(Method m: Axis.class.getDeclaredMethods())
            System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println("constructor:");
        System.out.println(Axis.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0]);
    }
}
```

will print

```
public static void Axis.main(java.lang.String[])
public static Axis[] Axis.values()
public static Axis Axis.valueOf(java.lang.String)
public Axis Axis.getOther()
constructor:
private Axis(java.lang.String,int,boolean)
```

So you see the compiler added methods as well as the constructor being `private` and having the additional parameters. Note, however, that it is up to the compiler, where and in which order it adds these two parameters. Since the constructor is `private` and only used within the class itself, there is no compatibility requirement about how the initialization exactly works.

Further, getting the `Constructor` reflectively doesn’t allow you to construct additional instances. The Reflection implementation recognizes that this is an `enum` and rejects such attempts. You would have to hack deeper into the implementation to make such things possible, but that’s counteracting the intention of `enum`s anyway.

Comment: I add empty constructor in my Enum, then I do reflect and call newInstance() method, but it throws NoSuchMethodException, it said I have only enmu(String, int) constructor, but no my empty constructor

Comment: That’s the point. You will always have the two additional parameters, regardless of how you defined your constructor. But in principle, there is no standard regarding the resulting signature. In theory, there are other possibilities to implement it on binary level. You can’t invoke the constructor reflectively, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Enum is abstract but you cannot actually extend it, except for some special circumstances, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063846/%D0%A1lasses-cannot-directly-extend-java-lang-enum) for more information.

Comment: All enums implicitly extend `java.lang.Enum`.

Comment: Yes you're right, but that's a little bit different from actually making a class that extends Enum.